# Indexing into an arrays with pointers of arrays

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to do some semi-complex object initializing for a raytracer in C++.

The following code is for adding triangular faces to an object via an array:

```
// "newTriangles" is a class; the object itself
// "faces" is an array of "triangle", a struct with three ints in it
// "nfaces" is an int of the number of faces which I use to initialize the array:
newTriangles->faces = new triangle[newTriangles->nFaces];

for (int i = 0; i < newTriangles->nFaces; ++i)
{
    // grab values
    newTriangles->faces[i].v1 = a;
    newTriangles->faces[i].v2 = b;
    newTriangles->faces[i].v3 = c;

    cout << i << ": " << newTriangles->faces[0].v1 << ", " << newTriangles->faces[0].v2 << ", " << newTriangles->faces[0].v3 << "\n";

    // Other code in this loop

    // Compute normal for this face
    coordinate v1 = {
        newTriangles->vertices[a].x,
        newTriangles->vertices[a].y,
        newTriangles->vertices[a].z };
    coordinate v2 = {
        newTriangles->vertices[b].x,
        newTriangles->vertices[b].y,
        newTriangles->vertices[b].z };
    coordinate v3 = {
        newTriangles->vertices[c].x,
        newTriangles->vertices[c].y,
        newTriangles->vertices[c].z };

    ray v1v2 = {
        v1.x - v2.x,
        v1.y - v2.y,
        v1.z - v2.z };
    ray v3v2 = {
        v3.x - v2.x,
        v3.y - v2.y,
        v3.z - v2.z };

    ray n = normalize(cross(v1v2, v3v2));
    newTriangles->fNormals[i].x = n.x;
    newTriangles->fNormals[i].y = n.y;
    newTriangles->fNormals[i].z = n.z;


    // This block here seems to be where the problem surfaces
    newTriangles->vNormals[i].x += n.x;
    newTriangles->vNormals[i].y += n.y;
    newTriangles->vNormals[i].z += n.z;

    double d = dot(newTriangles->fNormals[i], newTriangles->vertices[a]);
    newTriangles->d[i] = d;
}
```

I use this `cout` command to ensure that my values are getting put in properly. In this code, I'm only printing out the first element at index 0 to see what happens to it.

Here is some sample output when I try to initialize the array with 48 elements:

```
0: 6, 7, 15 (this is correct)
1: 6, 7, 15
2: 6, 7, 15

... (repeats)

28: 6, 7, 15
29: -422365367, -1077858410, 15
30: -422365367, -1077858410, -58508617
31: -422365367, -1077858410, -58508617

... (repeats)

47: -422365367, -1077858410, -58508617
```

So obviously during that loop where I'm initializing the array, my data is getting corrupted. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: Could you also provide the code that actually crashes?

Comment: I hope this is clear enough. It's tough to describe the problem without posting a ton of code to explain all the custom types I'm using.

Comment: I think this depends on what faces actually is. The comment says it is an array, but the code treats it as a pointer. Which is it?

Comment: @Bo Persson - It's a pointer to an array which is initialized dynamically at runtime.

Comment: can you provide us with the number of elements in `faces` and in `vertices`?  Also, in the expression `vertices[faces[i].v1]`, `i` refers to a `for` loop variable?  Can you paste the loop?  This just seems to me as a simple index out of bounds where you're mixing up array lengths...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the standard setup for mesh compression with:

1. `vertices` a list of `N` 3D points.
2. `faces` a list of `M` 3 index points, with `M` typically much larger than `N` (or this structure provides no benefit at the cost of requiring extra indirection and being painful to implement).

This setup is intended for compressing the structure be sharing each vertex between all adjacent triangles.  Each face stores 3 indices into the `vertices` array instead of 3 3D points.

The idea here is that you have **2 lists of different sizes**.  Implementing this setup, especially with raw, dynamically allocated arrays, in C or C++ is especially painful when you mix up `for` loop indices or array sizes.

Let's take a look at your setup.

```
ray ptr = {
        vertices[faces[i].v1].x - o.x,
        vertices[faces[i].v1].y - o.y,
        vertices[faces[i].v1].z - o.z };
```

I assume `faces` here points to the `newTriangles->faces` array you mention in the first part, and that this list has `newTriangles->nFaces` items.  I also assume this line to be inside some loop as follows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newTriangles->nFaces; ++i)
{
    ray ptr = {
        vertices[faces[i].v1].x - o.x,
        vertices[faces[i].v1].y - o.y,
        vertices[faces[i].v1].z - o.z };
    // ...
}
```

You repeat in your post and comments that this array is correctly allocated and has not been tampered with.  Sure, OK.  What about the other list? Where does this `vertices` array come from?  How many elements does **that list** contain? 8? 16?  I bet it's some number close to the limit that causes your crash.

Your post does not contain enough information for us to find your problem.  However, I can provide you with a quick checklist:

1. Make sure the loop over `i` is performed over the range `[0,nFaces)`.
2. If `faces[i].v1`, `faces[i].v2` and `faces[i].v3` don't match `a`, `b` and `c` in your initialization, some other part of your code has tampered with you array or you don't pass function arguments correctly, mismatching array sizes.
3. Check how `vertices` is allocated, and how many elements it contains.  Validate that `faces[i].v1`, `faces[i].v2` and `faces[i].v3` are **always** smaller than the number of entries in `vertices` (which, remember, does **not** have the same number of elements as `faces`).

Comment: I've done some more debugging after reading your suggestion #2 and have edited the question with some new findings.

Comment: You should check suggestion #3.  There is still no information on what the size of `newTriangles->vertices` is.  I suspect this is your problem.  Also, why is the print statement always outputting vertex 0?

Comment: é - The size of `newTriangles->vertices` is `nVertices`, a variable set by the user which matches the amount of vertex values provided. There should be no problems there. Also, I explicity told the print statement to ouput only vertex 0 so I could monitor what is happening to that specific variable as the loop runs. You can see that somehow it gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously run outside of your allocated area, and get further outside if you think you have allocated more space (but are not actually accessing the space you allocated). The actual declaration of `vertices` and `faces` seems to be interesting.

For example, it could be that you should use (*faces)[i] depending on the number of indirections there actually are.

Comment: I don't think I'm running outside the allocated area. Like I mentioned in the question, after I fill the array I can print it out fine. Then when I access it later in a method defined in the class definition, it fails even when I'm just trying to access the first element.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it you may be on the right track. The value in `faces[i].v1` looks like it could be an address. However I'm having trouble getting the value it points to.

Comment: @Andrew: arrays don't magically alter themselves.  If this were due to some external factor, such as a corrupted RAM, I doubt the symptoms would be the same at each execution.  There's a bug in your code; please help us help you find it!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::vector`, and then use .at() in all accesses. It will throw a nice exception for you where you've messed up. Nobody who wants to write correct programs uses native arrays, because as you've discovered, they're hideous.

Comment: s/uses native arrays/dynamically allocates native arrays/

Comment: AFAIK, this would not fix OP's problem, only prevent the debugger from automatically popping up at the right line (or getting a core dump).

Comment: @Andre: The OP's problem is that he's accessing bad memory. That won't tell him *why* it's invalid. Replacing his use of arrays with vectors will.

Comment: I agree that OP, contrarily to his belief, is accessing an array using an invalid index.  Although I agree with your recommendation (for other obvious reasons), replacing arrays with vectors will only change the symptoms, not the cause.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that you allocate at least 8 elements for the array.

Comment: Like I wrote, I allocate exactly as many elements as needed with the line `newTriangles->faces = new triangle[newTriangles->nFaces];`.

Comment: Like you didn't write, what are `a`, `b` and `c` in the initialization, `i` in the code that breaks and how many elements are there in the `vertices` array?